# NMOS to control electromagnet

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, electromagnet

[image]

I'm using a 3.3V output from a pmod port on a digilent Basys3 board. I have the circuit working IRL but I am required to provide a diagram and simulation. I'm not proficient in LTSpice and not 100% confident with MOSFETs. In my circuit, I'm using an IRF2708 MOSFET. The goal is to show that when the 3.3V is low, the 12V will power the electromagnet, and when it is high the magnet will be off. Resistor 3 is a 15ohm 25W power resistor. The inductor and resistor are to represent the electromagnet. I'm wondering if anyone could point out where I have made a mistake, thank you.[image]

Comment: The "electromagnet" circuit is floating. It has only one wire connecting it to the rest.

Comment: Another thing worth fixing is to right-click on the NMOS and "Pick new MOSFET", then select one close to the one you are using.  Then after that delete the diode since it's built into the MOSFET model itself.

Comment: Thank you, those two suggestions resolved the issue! I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Do you really intend to use a sine as a controlling voltage?